# How to set background image in div using map from JSON in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, database

I have an array like this in React data file and I'm using the .map() method to load JSON data in component `ProjectItem.js`.

How should I take the object "picture", render that as background image in div called `ProjectItem` inside map function in functional component? title and category objects appears on my web-app, but image isn't loading I just see the path url,, please help thanks.

**screenshot**

[image]
[image]

**data.json**

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Projecttitle1",
    "category": "frontend development",
    "picture": "../src/Assets/Images/Desktop/Portfolio_A4.png",
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Projecttitle2",
    "category": "frontend development",
    "picture": "../src/Assets/Images/Desktop/Portfolio_D4.png",
  }
]
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import projects from "./data.json";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="projectItem">
      {projects.map((el) => {
        return (
            <div key={el.id}
            style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${el.picture})`,
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        }}
      >
        <ul>
          <li>{el.title}</li>
          <li>{el.url}</li>
          <li>{el.category}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      );
    })}
   </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The path for your pictures is their location on your computer relative to your project folder. When you use that path to display the images the browser looks for them on the local hosted server, that means that you have to serve those images so they will be accessible.
Take a look at this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

I would upload the images to a storage service and replace the paths with the download URLs.

Comment: I tried moving images to public folder and backgroundImage:`url(${"PUBLIC_URL + el.picture"})` is not getting images loading. Am I using wrong url parameter?

Comment: @inhyechoi try to follow the guide in the link I've added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all your images inside the public folder, then set the actual url inside your array objects as follows -

```
{"id" : 1, 
  "picture" : "/Assets/Images/Desktop/Portfolio_A4.png"
//url should start from the directory inside the public folder, the just above directory of the mentioned url is - /Public*/Assets/Images/Desktop/Portfolio-A4.png* (try passing the url inside * * only)
}
```

All the pictures related to the projects are advisable to be kept inside public folder and then pass the path from the directory just inside the public folder to the url property.
Hope this helps